# how can I export hbase table using starttime endtime?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to perform incremental backup , I have already checked Export option but couldn't figure out start time option.Also please suggest on CopyTable , how can I restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue here, the hbase [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html) says

`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]`

so after trying a few of combinations, I found out that it is converted to a real example like below code

`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export  test /bkp_destination/test 1369060183200 1369063567260023219`

where 
***test***  is tablename, 
***/bkp_destination/test*** is backup destination folder,
***1369060183200*** is starttime,
***1369063567260023219*** is endtime

Answer (score 1):

Using [CopyTable](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#copytable) you just receive copy of given table on [the same or another cluster](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops.backup.html) (actually CopyTable MapReduce job). No miracle.

Its your own decision how to restore. Obvious options are:

- Use the same tool to copy table back.
- Just get / put selected rows (what I think you need here). Please pay attention you should keep timestamps while putting data back.

Actually for incremental backup it's enough for you to write job which scans table and gets/puts rows with given timestamps into table with the name calculated by date. Restore should work in reverse direction - read table with calculated name and put its record with the same timestamp.

I'd also recommend to you following technique: [table snapshot](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/introduction-to-apache-hbase-snapshots/) (CDH 4.2.1 uses HBase 0.94.2). It looks not applicable for incremental backup but maybe you find something useful here like additional API. From the point of view of backup now it looks nice.

Hope this will help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The source code suggests

**int versions = args.length > 2? Integer.parseInt(args[2]): 1;**

**long startTime = args.length > 3? Long.parseLong(args[3]): 0L;**

**long endTime = args.length > 4? Long.parseLong(args[4]): Long.MAX_VALUE;**

The accepted answer doesn't pass version as a parameter. How did it work then?

*hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export  test /bkp_destination/test 1369060183200 1369063567260023219*

From source code this boils down to -

1369060183200 - **args[2]** - version

1369063567260023219 - **args[3]** - starttime

Attaching source for ref:

```
private static Scan getConfiguredScanForJob(Configuration conf, String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scan s = new Scan();
    // Optional arguments.
    // Set Scan Versions
    int versions = args.length > 2? Integer.parseInt(args[2]): 1;
    s.setMaxVersions(versions);
    // Set Scan Range
    long startTime = args.length > 3? Long.parseLong(args[3]): 0L;
    long endTime = args.length > 4? Long.parseLong(args[4]): Long.MAX_VALUE;
    s.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime);
    // Set cache blocks
    s.setCacheBlocks(false);
    // set Start and Stop row
    if (conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START) != null) { 
      s.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytesBinary(conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START)));
    } 
    if (conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP) != null) { 
      s.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytesBinary(conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP)));
    } 
    // Set Scan Column Family
    boolean raw = Boolean.parseBoolean(conf.get(RAW_SCAN));
    if (raw) { 
      s.setRaw(raw);
    } 

    if (conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMN_FAMILY) != null) { 
      s.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(conf.get(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMN_FAMILY)));
    } 
    // Set RowFilter or Prefix Filter if applicable.
    Filter exportFilter = getExportFilter(args);
    if (exportFilter!= null) { 
        LOG.info("Setting Scan Filter for Export.");
      s.setFilter(exportFilter);
    } 

    int batching = conf.getInt(EXPORT_BATCHING, -1);
    if (batching !=  -1){
      try { 
        s.setBatch(batching);
      } catch (IncompatibleFilterException e) { 
        LOG.error("Batching could not be set", e);
      } 
    } 
    LOG.info("versions=" + versions + ", starttime=" + startTime + 
      ", endtime=" + endTime + ", keepDeletedCells=" + raw);
    return s;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explain. But when applying 'prefix' how to use it? I got confused in "getExportFilter(args)". If I want to export: version=1 and prefix='ABC-' then what would be my 'args'? "1 ABC-"? or something else? Thx